# Shifting bit values in C

Tags: c, bit, unsigned, bit-shift

Say I have the following code:

```
uint32_t fillThisNum(int16_t a, int16_t b, int16_t c){

      uint32_t x = 0;
      uint16_t temp_a = 0, temp_b = 0, temp_c = 0; 

      temp_a = a << 24;
      temp_b = b << 4;
      temp_c = c << 4;

      x = temp_a|temp_b|temp_c;

      return x;
}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is fill the 32-bit number with bit information that I can extract at a later time to perform different operations.

Parameter `a` would hold the first 24 bits of "data", `b` would hold the next 4 bits of "data" and `c` would hold the final 4 bits of "data".

I have a couple questions:

1. Do the parameters have to be the same bit length as the function type, and must they be unsigned?
2. Can I assign an unsigned int to a signed int? (i.e. `uint32_t a = int32_t b;`)
3. Can I fill a 32-bit number with the 16-bit parameters so long they don't exceed the length of the 32-bit return value.

Any advice/tips/hints would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Note: if `int` bit size is 16, `temp_a = a << 24;` is not well defined.

Comment: Usually better to do shifting with unsigned types vs. signed ones.

Comment: When you say "Do the parameters have to be the same bit length as the function type...", by "function type", do you mean the type of the return value of the function?

Comment: @plafratt Yes, if the return type is uint32_t, do the parameters have to be of type uint32_t as well.

Comment: Can you describe which bits of the 32-bit result are supposed to come from where? Your actual code only fills in (at most) the lower 16 bits of `x`, since all of the `temp`s are 16-bit, and it overlaps `b` with `c`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb What I WANT to do is completely fill `x` with the temporary variables. Would I need to cast the temps to a 32-bit type? Like this              `x = (uint32_t)temp_a|(uint32_t)temp_b|(uint32_t)temp_c|`  So it fills the entire return value? Parameter `a` would hold the first 24 bits of "data", `b` would hold the next 4 bits of "data" and `c` would hold the final 4 bits of "data".

Comment: @Srx2020 you have to actually move the bits into the right positions

Comment: @MattMcNabb Okay, I will work with some this sample code to get an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct way to write this code is:

```
uint32_t fillThisNum(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c)
{
// mask out the bits we are not interested in
    a &= 0xFFFFFF;    // save lowest 24 bits
    b &= 0xF;         // save lowest 4 bits
    c &= 0xF;         // save lowest 4 bits

// arrange a,b,c within a 32-bit unit so that they do not overlap
    return (a << 8) + (b << 4) + c;
}
```

By using an unsigned type for the parameters, you avoid any issues with signed arithmetic overflow, sign extension, etc.

It's OK to pass signed values as arguments when calling the function, those values will be converted to unsigned.

By using `uint32_t` as the parameter type then you avoid having to declare any temporary variables or worry about type width when doing your casting. It makes it easier for you to write clear code, this way.

You don't *have* to do it this way but this is a simple way to make sure you don't make any mistakes.

Comment: Very good yet simple explanation Matt.  Needed a lead in the right direction and this helped.  I can apply this logic to a much more complex problem now, thanks!

Comment: As I alluded to in my response, if you need to send 16-bit arguments, you can do so and then move them to 32-bit temps to set the appropriate bits in the return value.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do the parameters have to be the same bit length as the function type, and must they be unsigned?

No, the arguments and the return value can be different types.

> 2. Can I assign an unsigned int to a signed int? (i.e. uint32_t a = int32_t b;)

Yes, the value will be converted from a signed to an unsigned value. The bits in "b" will stay the same, so while "b" is in 2's complement, "a" will be a positive 32-bit number.

So, for example, let int8_t c = -127. If you perform an assignment uint8_t d = c, then "d" will be 129.

> 3. Can I fill a 32-bit number with the 16-bit parameters so long they don't exceed the length of the 32-bit return value.

If by that, you mean the way that you did in your code:

```
x = temp_a|temp_b|temp_c;
```

Yes, that is fine, with the caveat that @chux mentioned: you can't shift an n-bit value more than n bits. If you wanted to set bits more significant than bit 15 in x, a way to do this would be to set up one of the temp masks with a 32-bit value instead of a 16-bit one.

Comment: The code `int8_t c = 0x81;` could give any value to `c` or raise a signal (and must be described by the compiler documentation). This is *implementation-defined* behaviour.

Comment: That's interesting. Is that based on the C specification? If so, could you please provide a reference?

Can I instead say uint8_t c = -127?

Comment: Yes, C99 6.3.1.3/3 . `uint8_t c = -127;` is well-defined and is covered by 6.3.1.3/2.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did not know that. I figured the compiler did the same thing for both literals in all cases. I hope to have a look at the standard.

Comment: Is there a reason that you reference C99? Is this the same in the later standards?

Comment: In C11 it is the same numbering and text.  Note that `0x81` is a literal of type `int` and value `129`.